# Connecting to MS Access to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-4.5

I recently started learning ASP.NET 4.5 ActiveX Data Objects. When I am trying to connecting the MS Access database in Visual studio 2015 I am getting an exception “An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code”.
When I tried to use try catch statements the exception resolved but data is not getting inserted into database. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You need to figured out what the exception is that is getting thrown. It sounds like you just put all of the code in a `try` and left the `catch` empty which just swallows the error.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if this will answer your question but maybe it will help.  When I tried to connect to a database using OleDb or ODBC I had to go to data sources (odbc) and create my own data source to use.  The reason I had to do this is because my database is on a different server.  But with out seeing your code to know why your getting this exception I don't know if I give you anymore help.